# Nautilus saved search does not execute, but opens the XML in Firefox instead

Tags: nautilus, search

Saving a nautilus search seems brilliant, as described in
http://www.howtogeek.com/117494/7-ubuntu-file-manager-features-you-may-not-have-noticed/

But on my Ubuntu 16.04 the search is not executed. Instead the file is opened in Firefox.

When executed from the command line

```
> nautilus NEF.savedSearch
```

another instance of nautilus is opened instead of the search being executed.

This is the contents of the XML file generated after having saved the search:

```
;<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query version="1.0">
   <text>nef</text>
   <location>Desktop/Exif</location>
</query>
```